# how to know publish full command when I click publish in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, publish, devenv

[image]

I know when I Click 'Rebuild Solution'. it is something like below.

[msbuild C:\Users\Micheal\source\repos\Calculator\Calculator.sln -t:publish]

[image]

[image]

But I do not know what exact publish command is.

I guess it is [msbuild C:\Users\dkssu\source\repos\Calculator\Calculator.sln -t:publish] But it is wrong.
It just built and did not go further.

Here's my question.
How to intercept commands when I click something in visual studio (2017/2019)

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by "did not go further" - further to what? Based only on your screenshot, you have a _folder_ profile/target. So it will _publish_ the _compiled_ assets to said folder, based on the settings you defined.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue and let us know any feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Actually**, the command is different and you should note that `-t:publish` which only works for the publish of windows app projects.

**For asp net web projects**, you should use `PublishProfile` file which is a publish guidance file.

Use this:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=xxx\xxx\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml
```

**Although** `-t:publish` can work on asp net web projects successfully, in fact, it does not play any function. After all, the command is for windows app publish.

**For windows app projects**, it actually publish the project and it just doesn't show up in the default MSBuild log.

You should additionally use `-v:detailed` command to check the detailed log.

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.sln -t:publish -v:detailed
```

**And** when you finish the command, you can check under the build output folder(`bin\xxx`), it actually there.

[image]